# Different "last modified" date format on Apache 2.4 with mod_autoindex

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4, last-modified, mod-autoindex

I`m using ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4 on one machine, 
and ubutnu 12.04 with Apache 2.2 on other machine.

The issue, with mod_autoindex 'last modified' format is different on each machine.

For example: 
for some file in some directory: 
On Apache 2.2, last modified is '06-Mar-2017 16:23'
On Apache 2.4, last modified is '2017-03-06 16:23'

How can I change the date format on the Apache 2.4 ? 
Is it possible?

Best,
Idan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not configurable, it was changed between 2.2 and 2.4 upstream. That being said, yours is the second comment I've seen on this in the last two weeks.

Does it break anything for you, or is it just a curiosity?  It should be relatively straightforward to provide an option to go back.

Comment: Thanks Eric, it's definitely break some feature in my system, I hope there will be solution soon.